# call back jquery function in IE, 8, 7 browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-plugins

I have jquery plugin and that is working fine for all browser including IE 10 and IE 9.

I have HTML form, one of its drop down value is generating dynamically and values are coming from jQuery. I just simply calling this function in my HTML document.ready function so simplify i make simple another function  "pressMe()" in query plugin that is calling alert function but still not happening ..

```
$.fn.pressMe = function () {

  alert("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa");
}
```

html form page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>

    <script>

       $(document).ready(function () {

           $(this).pressMe();
       }
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
               // rest of code//
```

Comment: Any errors in the console? (F12)

Comment: SCRIPT1028: Expected identifier, string or number 
searchProperty_Plugin.js, line 744 character 33
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'pressMe' 
searchForm.html, line 29 character 16

Comment: Well there you go. check line 744 of the `searchProperty_Plugin.js` file

Comment: The problem must be elsewhere; this simple works http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/Fazuy/, but You miss a ) at the end of the document.ready function.

Comment: no i know ) is there... is just miss out while typing here.... !!!

Comment: what i am doing wrong ???                                                                                                             $("#MessageBox").dialog({

        title: messageTitle,
        buttons: [{ text: 'Ok', class: 'OkButton', click: function () { $(this).dialog('close'); } }]
    });

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, i was passing jquery class "ok_button" in jquery dialog and it was creating problem in IE 8 and IE 7 for some reason ....

```
 $("#MessageBox").dialog({ title: messageTitle, buttons: [{ text: 'Ok', class:  'OkButton', click: function () { $(this).dialog('close'); } }] })
```

solution :

```
function displayMessage(message, messageTitle) {


$("#MessageBox").text(message);

$("#MessageBox").dialog({

    title: messageTitle,
    buttons: [{ text: 'Ok', click: function () { $(this).dialog('close'); } }]
});
}
```

Comment: jQuery has dropped support for IE 7 and 8 so you need to consider that.